# Navigating encoder-only text/sentence embedding models

Tags: embeddings, evolutionary-algorithms

**tldr;** I am researching/looking for vec2text methods that work (a) without training a special model to guide the mutations, and (b) without access to the model weights.

I am doing some experiments in navigating the encoded space of an encoder-only text embedding model (such as OpenAI's [text-embedding-ada-002](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings/use-cases), but not specific to this model), with the **limitation that I do not have access to the weights**. I am trying to find some heuristics to "travel" towards a `target` embedding within the space.

Note: this is about text embedding (e.g sentences, maybe paragraphs), not word embedding.

Some ideas I currently have:

- Running an evolutionary algorithm to mutate the `text` in `(text, embedding)` pairs as individuals, and using `dist(embedding, target embedding)` as an objective.
- At each step, locally finding "directional" vectors by taking the delta of two steps combined with some adjective, and associating meaning to the direction.
- Applying a direction repeatedly if it gets me closer to the target.
- Asking an LLM to {mutate, combine} an/two individuals' text, and also to tell me the semantic difference (giving meaning to the direction).
- Inspiration/existing research: I am aware of the Vec2Text from [Text Embeddings Reveal (Almost) As Much As Text](https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.06816), but i am specifically looking to do as well as possible **without training a special model to guide the mutations**.
- Q: Is there any existing research on this sort of thing?
- Q: Any better mutation heuristics? Other approaches entirely?
- Q: I vaguely aware of the [Manifold Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold_hypothesis), are there ways to detect if an embedding is far from the manifold? Or a way to "get back" to the manifold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embedding space of different models may be more similar than you think. Your problem reminds me a bit of blackbox adversarial attacks, where you want to e.g., find an adversarial example targeting some API to induce an output without having access to model weights.

For example, [Zou et al., 2023](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2307.15043.pdf) and [Wallace et al., 2019](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.07125.pdf) both suggest finding adversarial examples with whitebox access to an ensemble of models (through gradient steps + discrete updates), with the goal being to induce certain types of outputs (e.g., toxic/harmful, different sentiment etc.). They then notice that these examples transfer to models that you only have API access to. This is pretty directly transferrable to your setting: take gradient steps + discrete updates (as described in the papers) to match the embeddings of an ensemble of whitebox models, then this might end up transferring to whatever blackbox API you're targeting.